# Eleminar elementos repetidos en un archivo .txt

Tags: java

tengo un archivo llamado digamos ejemplo.txt en el que tengo los siguientes numeros.

```
1323
7445
1323
5345
3455
1323
```

Y me preguntaba como podria eliminar los repetidos, en este caso el numero 1323 y dejar que solo quede uno, que quede de esta forma:

```
7445
5345
3455
1323
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra alternativa (con streams) seria usar HashSet, ya que no permite duplicados.

### Main:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        String fileName = "pathtofile.txt";
        Set<String> list = new HashSet<String>();
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            list = lines
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          //capturar la excepción
        }
        
        //imprimir en consola
        list.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
        
        //Reemplazar archivo
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        Iterator<String> it = list.iterator(); 
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            out.write(it.next());
            out.newLine();
        }
        out.close();
        
    }
}
```

Finalmente este seria el archivo txt reemplazado:

```
1323
3455
7445
5345
```

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es usar Streams que nos brinda Java 8.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/crack81/Desktop/file.txt"))) {

            List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

            while(sc.hasNext()){
                numbers.add(sc.nextLine());
            }

            List<String> filtered = numbers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

            filtered.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```